# Snow R: Get Currently Running Node Info

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snow

Let's say we have a cluster of 4 CPU's in R through SNOW.

How can I find out which Node is running?

I want do to logic like this:

IF (Node 1) THEN logic1
IF (Node 2) THEN logic2
IF (Node 3) THEN logic3
IF (Node 4) THEN logic4

How can I implement the IF condition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like a ID for each of the workers in your cluster, you could use "clusterApply" to initialize a global variable on each of the workers:

```
library(snow)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(4)
clusterApply(cl, seq_along(cl), function(i) workerID <<- i)
```

Then your "node check" logic could be written as:

```
fun <- function(task) {
  if (workerID == 1)
    sqrt(task)
  else if (workerID == 2)
    log(task)
  else if (workerID == 3)
    log10(task)
  else if (workerID == 4)
    exp(task)
  else
    -1
}
clusterApplyLB(cl, 1:10, fun)
```

If you're using snow with an MPI cluster, you can use the "mpi.comm.rank" function instead, but it numbers the workers from `0` to `n-1`.

People often use an expression such as `paste(Sys.info()[['nodename']], Sys.getpid(), sep='-')` as a unique worker ID, but that's a bit awkward for this example.